# Java: Unable to access jarfile when running as an admin

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar file named test.jar, which I am running with a batch script from the same folder.
Here's the batch code:

```
java -jar test.jar
pause
```

The jar itself works with no problems, and I can run it just fine.
However, if I try to run the batch file as an administrator (by right clicking it and choosing "Run as Administrator"), I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile test.jar
```

I'm using Windows 8.1, but this also happened on a machine running Windows 7.
What can I do to be able to run this as an Administrator?

Comment: This can be due to UAC. Check [this](http://superuser.com/questions/139841/access-denied-even-though-im-an-administrator) and [this](http://think-like-a-computer.com/2011/05/11/windows-access-denied-folder-administrator/)

Comment: (by right clicking it and choosing "Run as Administrator") --> Here "by right clicking it" means your jar file? R u running your jar file by right click and Run as administartor or you are running you batch file?

Comment: @Jayaprasad I mean running the batch file as an admin.

Comment: @payeli I have UAC disabled in my system.

Comment: @Opalium just for a test try to run the command line as admin and inside of it try to run the batch. What is the resul?

Comment: @prmottajr I have done so and it worked. Weird... I wonder why the batch file doesn't work then?

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problem that you and i solved it by changing

```
java -jar test.jar
```

to

```
java -jar %~dp0test.jar
```

%~dp0 holds the directory of your bat file (AFAIK) so %~dp0 will give Java the full path to the jar file solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could also ad a temp path to java

path=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin
Java script
path=