# Unable to access folder inside current directory when run as admin

Tags: java, batch-file

My problem is similar to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739732/java-unable-to-access-jarfile-when-running-as-an-admin). I have batch file as below which is suppose to be executed on Windows7 & Windows 8/8.1:

```
@echo off
java -jar %~dp0build\jar\Installer.jar
pause
```

**I have folder structure as :**

OMS

Installer.bat

build

-classes

-jar

I am a user with full admin permissions. When I double click on bat file,it is able to access **OMS folder**. But when I right click and run as administrator, it gives error as :

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\OMS (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I am refering this OMS folder in java code as:

```
File srcFolder = new File("./OMS/");
```

How should I make it access current directory's folder when running as Administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start your file like:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
```

batch files ran with admin privileges by default start in `%windir%\system32`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The exact line made it work. I was not knowing about the default start.